# matcher function typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use typeahead's matcher function to check if my search returns no results. If it returns no results i want to append a div on the end of the search bar. However the matcher function is causing my highlighter to break and return random results. Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this without using the matcher function or how use it properly in this instance? I think i might be taking the wrong approach.

```
$('.shop_search').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            map = {};
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                map[data.text] = {
                    address: data.text2,
                    name: data.text,
                    post: data.post
                };
                shops.push(data.text);
            });
            process(shops);
            shops = [];
        },

        minLength: 3,
        matcher: function (item) {
            if (item.indexOf(this.query) == -1) {
                $(".dropdown-menu").append($('<li><button class="btn" >Advanced                                                   Search</button></li>'));
                return true;
            }
        },

        highlighter: function (item) {
            var p = map[item];
            var itm = ''
                     + "<div class='typeahead_primary'>" + p.name + "</div>"
                     + "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>" + p.address +  </div>"
                     + "</div>"
                     + "</div>";
            return itm;
        },
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you forgot a "

```
+ "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>" + p.address +  </div>"
```

should be

```
+ "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>" + p.address +  "</div>"
```